# Замена класса при нажатии на <li>

Tags: javascript

столкнулся с проблемой - не могу сделать так, что-бы при нажатии на li ему полностью заменялся класс на "selected", подскажите пожалуйста как правильно реализовать без дополнительных библиотек.

Comment: а в чем сложность? навесить обработчик клика и заменить список классов

Comment: я не могу понять какой кусок кода нужен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите здесь:
https://javascript.ru/forum/dom-window/53117-izmenit-klass-li-pri-nazhatii-na-menyu.html
Там подробное описание по вашему вопросу

Comment: спасибо огромное )

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)